# Is $\tilde H^*({RP}^n;Z_2)\cong H^*({RP}^n;Z_2)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Since $\tilde H^i({RP}^n;Z_2)\cong H^i({RP}^n;Z_2)$ when $i\ge 1$, and $\tilde H^0({RP}^n;Z_2)=Z_2= H^0({RP}^n;Z_2)$, can I say $\tilde H^*({RP}^n;Z_2)\cong H^*({RP}^n;Z_2)$?

Comment: If your premises were true, you could certainly say that. They aren't.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez where is false?

Comment: What is false is clearly stated in Alejo's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your definition of reduced cohomology? Normally, one considers the augmented singular complex
$$\cdots \to C_2 (X) \to C_1 (X) \to C_0 (X) \xrightarrow{\epsilon} \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$
then applies the contravariant functor $\operatorname{Hom} (-, G)$, and the cohomology of the resulting complex is by definition $\tilde{H}^\bullet (X, G)$. The relation between $\tilde{H}^\bullet (X,G)$ and $\tilde{H}_\bullet (X)$ is given by the universal coefficient theorem, and in particular, we have
$$\tilde{H}^0 (X,G) \cong \operatorname{Hom} (\tilde{H}_0 (X), G).$$
As $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ is connected, we have $\tilde{H}_0 (\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n) = 0$.

Comment: Reduced cohomology is identified to cohomology relative to a basepoint, and we use relative cup products

Comment: @6666 It is still the same thing, calculating something "relative to a point" and working with the augmented complex. So the answer is no.

Comment: Having $\tilde{H}_0 = \tilde{H}^0 = 0$ for connected spaces (or rather having trivial (co)homology for a point) is kind of the whole point of the reduced (co)homology.